# Start bash session without history

Tags: bash, command-history

There are several options to disable saving commands to bash history e.g.

```
set +o history
```

or

```
unset HISTFILE
```

How to start a new bash session with history disabled?

I tried `bash +o history` but it didn't work.

EDIT: I don't want to modify my rc or profile files. I just want to start a single bash session with a different configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bash --init-file <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; unset HISTFILE')
```

OR

```
bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; unset HISTFILE')
```

And better put it in `~/.bash_aliases` as permanent alias:

```
alias bash2="bash --init-file <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; unset HISTFILE')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently disable history you can add `shopt -u -o history` or `set +o history` to your `~/.bashrc`, or `/etc/profile`. Then clear your history!

```
history -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `set +o history` option in:

```
~/.bashrc
```

(it might change depending on the distro)

Then clear the history with:

```
history -c
```

Log off and log on again.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution was posted in a comment, which I think should be one of the answers here

Execute this command to start a bash shell that does not save any commands to history :

```
HISTFILE= bash
```

Comment: Does this work even if .bashrc sets HISTFILE?

Comment: No it does not. the .bashrc sets the HISTFILE again after we unset it

Answer (score 0):

```
export HISTFILE=
```

And commands in that session will not be saved. Commands in other terminal windows or sessions will still be saved as usual.